# How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin work?

Tags: .htaccess, domain-name

I am designing a tumblr theme, I am trying to embed a font. In order to do so I need to host the font in my server; but there is the cross-domain restriction (which to be honest I don't know how it works)

I know that I need to add this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` somewhere; But I don't know where. From somethings I read it says you need to add it on a php file, but tumblr does not use php but only html

Unfortunately I am so lost that I can't really give any more details. I hope you could help

Comment: put this in your .htaccess `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: I don't think you need that at all for web fonts